# React-router links don't get visited style

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I've got a small website I'm building with React Router. I've noticed that only the homepage link gets the visited styles. The other link does not get the visited style, even when you visit it.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfzkavbd/2/

Javascript:

```
var dom = React.DOM;

var Router = React.createFactory(ReactRouter.Router);
var Link = React.createFactory(ReactRouter.Link);

var NavItem = React.createFactory(React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var item = {
            marginLeft: "15px",
            marginRight: "15px",
            position: "relative",
            height: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center"
        };
        return dom.div({ style: item }, this.props.children);
    }
}));

var NavBar = React.createFactory(React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var navBarStyle = {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            height: "50px",
            display: "flex"
        };
        var innerNavBarStyle = {
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "initial",
            flexGrow: "1",
            color: "#777"
        };
        return dom.div({ style: navBarStyle },
            dom.div({ style: innerNavBarStyle }, 
                this.renderRightSide()
        ));
    },
    renderRightSide: function() {
        var rightStyle = {
            marginLeft: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            height: "100%"
        };
        return dom.div({ style: rightStyle }, 
            NavItem(null, Link({ to: "/Blog" }, "Blog")),
            NavItem(null, Link({ to: "/" }, "Home"))
        );
    }
}));

var Blog = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return dom.span(null, "Blog");
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return dom.div(null,
            NavBar(),
            this.props.children
        );
    }
});

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return dom.span(null, "Home");
    }
});

const routes = {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'Blog', component: Blog },
    { path: '/', component: Home }
  ]
};

ReactDOM.render(Router({ routes: routes }), document.getElementById("App"));
```

HTML:

```
<html class=""><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div id="App" class="app"></div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.app a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.app a:visited  {
  color: red;
}
.app a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

How can I apply my visited style to all the visited links?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package and set the class for visited links to true in an onClick event handler. That would not persist across reloads though. If you wanted that you would need to save the setting to local storage or something.